# Spliting a string by operators,identifiers n others in c

Tags: c, math, wolfram-mathematica

I have a string like "id1*id2+100; for(i=0;i<5;i++); if (a>b) then c=70;"
Now i want to split the string by the operators, identifiers n others like.......

output:

operators:

*

+.......

identifiers:
id1
id2..........

others:
for
if
then
c...........

I know splitting a string into tokens like....

```
int main()
{
 char str[]=" b = a + c ; for (i =0;i<5;i++ )";
 char *Pch;Pch=strtok(str,"  ;");
 int i=1;
 printf("Splitting string \"%s\" into token \n",str);
 while(Pch!=NULL)
 {
     printf("[%d]    %s\n",i,Pch);
    i++;
     Pch=strtok(NULL," ; ");
 }

 return 0;
}
```

but i don't know how to split a string by that all.....i want help from u all.pls pls..

Comment: whats this to do with mathematica?

Answer (score 0):

Well seems to me like you're trying to parse a specific syntax. Now you have to choices :

1. writing a parser by yourself - in that case look up on LL parsers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser)
2. Making use of a tool, that enables you to write a productions (grammar rules [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_(computer_science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_%28computer_science%29) ) and then make use of the generated code. Take a look at Bison (produces LALR(1) http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/ ), or ANTLR(produces LL(1) http://www.antlr.org/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to have lexical analyzer to extract tokens from input string. Flex (with Bison, maybe?) is a good choice to start. You can always write your own lexer and/or syntax analyzer if you wish.

I started my adventure with lexers by digging what FSM (Finite State Machine) is.

Ref. title: "Dragon Book"